# Can't open AVD manager in Visual Studio, internet connection error message

Tags: visual-studio-2017, android-device-manager

I am new to Xamarin and trying to set up a virtual device using the ADM (Android Device Manager) in Visual Studio 2017. When I click to open the ADM it looks like it's loading for a moment and then pops up the error message "Android SDK instance could not be loaded. Please check your internet connection."
[image: SDK instance could not be loaded]

I know that I am connected to the internet, I was even able to download and install packages in VS. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I'm guessing it's some sort of issue with VS not knowing where my SDK is installed. I also tried opening the SDK manager (tools >android >android sdk manager) and navigating to the folder to show Visual Studio where my SDK is installed but even that window won't load up properly so I can't set the path! It gives the error message "Loading SDK component information failed. Please Retry." I did retry but nothing changes.

[image: loading sdk component info failed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution

In Visual Studio Go to Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager

When the SDK manager starts, go to the bottom right hand corner and click the button with a cog on it

Go to Repository and select Google (Unsupported)

I was then able to use the Android Device Manager and create a new device

You can change it back to the Microsoft (Supported) when complete

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.5

Comment: Thanks @rideintothesun ! I was able to open the ADM after changing to Google repository. The button for the setting was on the bottom RIGHT corner for me. I tried switching back to Microsoft and the problem came back, so I'll stick with Google for now. Doesn't seem to address the root of the problem but as long as I can run virtual devices...

Answer (score 1):

Is this due to capacity issues in Azure. I'm sure this worked with the current version of Visual Studio 2017 I have been using 15.9.5

Comment: So could I potentially solve the problem by using a different version of VS or deleting a couple of my virtual devices? FYI I already have 4 virtual devices because I was using Android Studio

Comment: I'm not sure that this would help, myself and my colleague both cannot access this. I don't think this is a Visual Studio issue, its whatever it is connecting to seems to be the issue